# OSM import: some features are missing

Tags: openstreetmap, spatialite, qgis-2, import

After importing OSM-Data to my qgis-project (as SpatiaLite database and/or shapefile-extract from planet.osm), some features are missing or have no attribute values. For example that lake: http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/552029 
Its just missing in the shapefile-import and the SpatiaLite import have the gemoetries of the lake, but no values!

[image]

The most other features are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you display is not the relation, but the closed way http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/55075809 (look for the id field).

This way has no tags, because they are in the relation http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/552092.

The OSM plugin import lacks full relation support as it is done by osm2pgsql. With that, relations get a negative ID to distinguish them from ways.

Try to load the data with `Add vector layer`. It can handle multipolygon relations a bit better (but still not optimal).

The shapefile extracts only cover most wanted features. Your relation does not belong to that group. You get full data support in shapefile format only when you pay for it.

Comment: I don't think there is a service that converts relation with non standard tags.

Comment: Well, there is: http://www.geofabrik.de/en/data/shapefiles.html

Comment: Thank you so far! But I hoped to hear something else... So, It seems that there are no (free) solution yet, to use OSM-Data in QGIS with its relations?

Comment: osm2pgsql is absolutely free! You just have to set up a postgis database yourself. It even runs on my Windows laptop (not the whole world). Have you tried with `Add Vector layer`?

Comment: I tried it with "add Vector layer", but the polygons are still missing. With postgis, the relations will work? Why not with SpatiaLite? I have trouble getting postgis running on my ubuntu...

Comment: osm2pgsql only talks to postgis databases.The logic behind it is rather complex, and not yet fully implemented in any spatialite importer. You can try spatialite_osm_map from gaia-gis.it and see if you get happy with it.